# Reading a text file using Pandas where some rows have empty elements?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset in a textfile that looks like this.

```
    0    0CF00400 X       8  66  7D  91  6E  22  03  0F  7D       0.021650 R
    0    18EA0080 X       3  E9  FE  00                           0.022550 R
    0    00000003 X       8  D5  64  22  E1  FF  FF  FF  F0       0.023120 R
```

I read this using

```
file_pandas = pd.read_csv(fileName, delim_whitespace = True, header = None, engine = 'python')
```

And got the output

```
    0   0  0CF00400  X   8  66  7D  91        6E  22    03    0F    7D  0.02165   
    1   0  18EA0080  X   3  E9  FE   0  0.022550   R  None  None  None      NaN   
    2   0  00000003  X   8  D5  64  22        E1  FF    FF    FF    F0  0.02312
```

But I want this read as

```
    0   0  0CF00400  X   8  66  7D  91        6E  22    03    0F    7D  0.021650   R  
    1   0  18EA0080  X   3  E9  FE  00                                  0.022550   R
    2   0  00000003  X   8  D5  64  22        E1  FF    FF    FF    F0  0.023120   R
```

I've tried removing `delim_whitespace = True` and replacing it with `delimiter = "  "` but that just combined the first four columns in the output shown above, but it did parse the rest of the data correctly, meaning that the rest of the columns were like the origin txt file (barring the NaN values in whitespaces).

I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Side note: the `00` is being parsed as only `0`. Is there a way to display `00` instead?

Comment: this looks like a fixed width file, can you try `read_fwf` also do you have tabs or spaces here? to preserve the `00` you'll need to pass `dtype=np.object`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like your data is fixed width columns, you can try `pandas.read_fwf()`:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO("""0    0CF00400 X       8  66  7D  91  6E  22  03  0F  7D       0.021650 R
0    18EA0080 X       3  E9  FE  00                           0.022550 R
0    00000003 X       8  D5  64  22  E1  FF  FF  FF  F0       0.023120 R"""), 
                 header = None, widths = [1,12,2,8,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,16,2])
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your method but the values in columns 4-11 were all separated with a whitespace. Like 6 6, 6 7, etc. However, using just `read_fwf()` without the widths argument worked really well! I just have the issue of the `00` showing up as `0`. I tried `dtype = np.object` but `dtype` isn't supported with the python engine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `converters = {6:str}` argument to avoid the column to be converted to `int`, try this `df = pd.read_fwf(file_name, header = None, converters = {6:str})`

Comment: Was able to try that argument out only today, it worked! Thanks!